# unreal engine 4 open level (by name) does not work?

Tags: game-development, unreal-engine4

[image]

Hi, I am new in unreal engine platform. Now, I am studying a first person shooter project. I did everything but I could not make work start button. I tried a lot of thing to start button work. Firstly, I fixed the name of map because the name of map should be same. Secondly, I have entered the map files to the packages in the project settings. But I could not find any other thing to fix the mistake. There are no error except building color errors. İs it related to it or are there any other thing to fix it? Also, İt works for other maps. However, it does not work for first person shooter map. What should I do. I really worked hard to do this project and I was too excited.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure capitalization is correct, if not try opening level by string instead of object reference. Also try putting a print string after your button is clicked to make sure the program is actually running. If the program is not running than make sure that the z order is at like 10 in the add to viewport block. As a last resort, add the open level to your player character, if that dosen't work, consider making a new project, verifying the engine (epic games launcher only) or install a later engine version (i.e 4.27 or 4.26) if you are on an older one (though I think open level by object reference is only in 4.27)

here are some opening levels with widget examples:

[Opening level by object reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6AG2.png)

[Open level by name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTUIz.png)

Edit: Click the blue text (hyperlinks) to open the imgur website with the images (idk why there isnt a preview)

Answer (score 0):

I never thought I should try to not use the name,
My issue was in UE5, but it also has the open level by Object reference
this solved my issue.

speaking of long names, there is something in the editor settings > Enable support for long paths ( >260 characters) - even in 4.27